# How to load database from file mdb ( microsoft access file) in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android and making a sample app to load database from package/assets/test.mdb

I try to follow [this turorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) 
My problem is that i don't know how to work with *.mdb.

Do i have to convert to specify database or just directly work with this file ?

And in this case database file has big amount (200 MB), so what should i do ?

Thanks !

Comment: `.mdb` - microsoft access file?

Comment: yes , microsoft access file. Could you suggestion me some ideas ?

Comment: Unless MS decides to release "Access for Android", you're not likely to find anything on android that read that .mdb file. You'll have to use Access on a Windows box to export it to a .csv or other DB format that android CAN read, like sqlite.

Comment: So don't talk about android . Can we write a java class to convert it ?

Comment: Sure, if you want to spend a few years reverse engineering the .mdb file format. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to a Microsoft Acess Database File, it cannot be read with Android.

You must [move](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/code-samples-tips/78-how-convert-access-database-sqlite-database.html) the data from a MS Access Database File over to a SQLite database file. The previous link has some information on how to do this.

Comment: yes, a microsoft access file. So i need to convert to another file ? Could i convert it then push into package android or run app to convert it then use the new file db ?

Comment: @Chameron see my edits. You will have to manually move the data over, exporting from MS Access, importing with SQLite browser. Then you *should* be able to read it in Android if it is the correct version (sqlite3 I think it is).

Comment: thanks. So i have to convert it to SQL database before include in to package. But we can write a class to convert it in flow of app ? :D any suggestion ?

Comment: No you cannot write a class to convert in flow of app because it would require reading an MS Access DB in Android, which cannot be done.

Comment: Huhm i new to java and android so i thought simply that there is java lib to do it. new question not about the android , only the java. We can write a java class to do it ? :D Thank

Comment: https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=java+access+database+driver&pbx=1&oq=java+access+database+driver&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=429l8352l0l8451l41l15l14l10l14l1l269l2584l0.9.6l36l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=1bddd5520996bb0f&biw=1680&bih=912